# Link not working in asp.net master page for some reason

Tags: asp.net, html, hyperlink

I am working on asp.net website using webforms & i am facing strange problems for some unknown reason.

I am different banner in different areas of teh page & one common banner in the header section of the MasterPage, Banner show up as it should but problem is that link with the banner is not working.

Below is the partial code generated after page display.

```
<div class="horizontalBannerBar">
<!-- Header Banner  -->
    <div class="pnlHeaderBanner" id="pnlHeaderBanner">

        <a target="_blank" href="http://abc.com" class="bannerlink" id="hypLnkHeaderBanner"><img style="border-width:0px;" src="../images/Banners/32dfe9ee-0832-4d89-8c61-45b0ef371f1f.jpg" id="imgHeaderBanner"></a>

</div>
<!-- Header Banner  -->
</div>
```

I am using Panel as a wrapper so that i can hide the banner in case banner is not present .

Below us the Code i use to assign value to hyperlink control & image control

```
DataSet ds = DataProvider.GetTopBanner(ArticleID, PageID, IssueID, CategoryID, BannerLayoutPosition, LangID);
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    imgHeaderBanner.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImagePath"].ToString();
    hypLnkHeaderBanner.NavigateUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BannerURL"].ToString();
}
else
{
    imgHeaderBanner.Visible = false;
    pnlHeaderBanner.Visible = false;
}
```

Actual .ASPX page code

```
<div class="horizontalBannerBar">
<!-- Header Banner  -->
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlHeaderBanner" CssClass="pnlHeaderBanner" runat="server">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypLnkHeaderBanner" CssClass="bannerlink"  runat="server" Target="_blank">
            <asp:Image ID="imgHeaderBanner" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" />
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </asp:Panel>
<!-- Header Banner  -->
</div>
```

It seems HTML is breaking up somewhere but i am not able to see it even on fiddle it doent work in FF & Chrome while link works in IE 9..

[Example LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/hvbZ7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `z-index: -999;` in your CSS. If you set it to 0 then your link will work.

Comment: I just changed the css to following & it works now `.horizontalBannerBar
{
   background-color: #A78944;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
   
}
.pnlHeaderBanner
{
 padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
 height:90px;
}
.horizontalHeaderBar
{
background-color: #AB1B56;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
 z-index: -999;
}`

Comment: z-index was actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Also the `<img />` tag is not properly closed in the HTML sample you posted at the top. I doubt that's the actual HTML generated by ASP.NET though.

```
<div class="horizontalBannerBar">
<!-- Header Banner  -->
    <div class="pnlHeaderBanner" id="pnlHeaderBanner">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://abc.com" class="bannerlink" id="hypLnkHeaderBanner">
            <img style="border-width:0px;" src="../images/Banners/32dfe9ee-0832-4d89-8c61-45b0ef371f1f.jpg" id="imgHeaderBanner" />
        </a>
    </div>
<!-- Header Banner  -->
</div>
```